# jQuery wordpress plugin conflict

Tags: jquery, plugins, conflict

I am using a wp theme and a plugin named wpml. I am no jQuery expert but as far as i understand there is a problem with it. I found a few posts from stackoverflow and tried what they said, at least I now know the problem.

```
TypeError: jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker is not a function
```

[Break On This Error]

jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker();

This is the error I got from firebugs' console tab :(
When I disable the wpml plugin everything works fine but unfortunately I paid for it..
Can someone give me an idea? I have been commenting codes, ui gets funnier every time i try:) but could not solve the real issue.

http://goo.gl/dFplb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are 2 instance of jQuery loaded on your page. It seems that the wpml plugin does not use the `dependencies` parameter in wordpress `wp_enqueue_script`. You need to remove the load to this one `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://otel.gratastest.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2"></script>` on yoour wpml plugin code. And you need to find it though.

Comment: No luck, I tried to find it but could not. I mailed to plugin owner and I got this answer as solution "Pleaseuse the latest version"...I said I am already using it but nothing came up:(

Comment: @cevizmx So, how does this become an answer then? Have you managed the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

I would try including [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)  before you include your plugin link. It's likely that datepicker is an unmentioned requirement for your plugin.

The problem is that the code doesn't know of any function named `datepicker`, which should be defined in the datepicker plugin above.

To test, datepicker should be included in the jQueryUI package hosted here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **inspect** in chrome by using console to monitor which plugin is creating problems. You don't have to disable all the plugins to check one by one which will consume more time.